# Did I burn out the data pin on my LEDs?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, led-strip, esp32, ws2812b

I had my 500 WS2812Bs working. Power injection all along and they were working good for the most part. They had a little flicker when they turned white so I was adding the recommended resistor and capacitor. Well I'm new to all of this and I incredibly stupidly put a capacitor inline on the data line before the lights. Now my lights do not work even after I took that off and tried different pins on my ESP32. Did I destroy all of them? Just the first one? Something else?

Comment: Hard to tell. Very unlikely that you damaged more than the first one. Not even sure why that would be damaging, to be honest. I'd rather bet on your power supply having a surge if anything is actually broken. In my experiecne, these beasts are rather resilient, but beginner's connections aren't. Make sure your solder contacts are sound.

Comment: Try bypassing the first one. But first check the voltage output on your power supplies.

Comment: Are those 5V LEDs or 12V? Was the capacitor charged when you soldered it? Did you solder it with incorrect polarity? Also check the ESP32's output is still working...

Comment: @bobflux  The LEDs are 5v. All of that's completely possible.